# Flex Slider issues after upgrading Drupal to v7.39

Tags: javascript

I've been researching this issue for a week to no avail.  Perhaps someone has some suggestions?
Upgraded a site from Drupal 7.34 to 7.39 rather seamlessly.  Also updated all modules that were down level.  All seemed OK.  But then the flex slider just stopped displaying.  I've checked all I could in the various display and definitions pages and all looks fine.  I've tried different browsers and even a different server instance with on luck.
I'm just hoping someone who may have experienced this anomalie can shet some light on what to look for next?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but in the `admin/config/development/performance` section I unchecked the compress javascript option, saved the page and suddenly my flex-slider images returned.  Strange though, isn't it?

Anyway - solved.